# UILabel -- WordWrap -- Frame Issue

Tags: ios, uitableview

A UILabel in my App is behaving unusually and I'm wondering if anyone has any ideas or suggestions on how to resolve it.

1.First I set the frames of the labels which will both appear inside the cell of a tableView.

```
CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 75);
CGRect Label1Frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 290, 20);
CGRect Label2Frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 290, 50);
UILabel *lblTemp;

UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:CellFrame        reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

1. Then I set the properties of labels

1.

```
lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label1Frame];
lblTemp.tag = 1;
lblTemp.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
lblTemp.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
lblTemp.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lblTemp.numberOfLines = 0;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];

//Initialize Label with tag 2.
lblTemp = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:Label2Frame];
lblTemp.tag = 2;
lblTemp.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10];
lblTemp.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
lblTemp.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
lblTemp.numberOfLines = 0;
[cell.contentView addSubview:lblTemp];

return cell;
```

3.Then I setup the contents of the cell

```
//set up the cell

UILabel *lblTemp1 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:1];
UILabel *lblTemp2 = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:2];

CaseFeed *aCaseFeed = [[CaseFeed alloc] init];
aCaseFeed = [CaseFeedbook objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

lblTemp1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aCaseFeed.title];
lblTemp2.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aCaseFeed.description];

cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;

return cell;
```

PROBLEM:  The contents of lblTemp2 (the second label in the cell) will span 2 or more lines.  During runtime, when the text of lblTemp2 is populated, the first two lines appear perfectly, however the third line starts outside the left side of the frame.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?  Why is this happening?

Comment: [@ehul](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1354417/ehul) did you get your problem solved..

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code to setup your cell of a tableView

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    else 
    {
        for (id v in cell.contentView.subviews) 
        {
            UIView *realV = (UIView *) v;
            [realV removeFromSuperview];
        }
    }
    CGRect CellFrame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 75);
    CGRect Label1Frame = CGRectMake(10, 5, 290, 20);
    CGRect Label2Frame = CGRectMake(0, 20, 290, 50);


    UILabel *label1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label1.frame = Label1Frame;
    label1.tag = 1;
    label1.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:12.0];
    label1.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
    label1.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label1.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label1];

    UILabel *label2 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    label2.frame = Label2Frame;
    label2.tag = 2;
    label2.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:10.0];
    label2.textColor = [UIColor lightGrayColor];
    label2.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    label2.numberOfLines = 0;
    [cell.contentView addSubview:label2];

    CaseFeed *aCaseFeed = [[CaseFeed alloc] init];
    aCaseFeed = [CaseFeedbook objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    label0.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aCaseFeed.title];
    label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", aCaseFeed.description];

    cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryDisclosureIndicator;
    return cell;
}
```

Hope this helps